# Understanding reads and their amount

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Long story short, I have a hard time understanding reads.

I have a small app, like 20 unique users in a peak like that, most of them are anonymus users (90%+). Only registered users are able to load/request multiple documents. Everyone is allowed to save.

The only queries I am currently using:

```
getDocumentReference: (surveyId: string) => {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('Surveys').doc(surveyId);
},

updateTransaction: (transaction: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise<void>) => {
    logging.dev('Run transaction update');
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .runTransaction(transaction)
        .catch((error) => {
            logging.dev(error);
        });
},

createSurvey: (survey: Survey): Promise<DocumentReference<DocumentData>> => {
    logging.dev('Create survey for: ' + survey.owner);
    return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('Surveys')
        .add({
            title: survey.title,
            description: survey.description,
            owner: survey.owner ?? 'anon',
        });
},

deleteSurvey: async (survey: Survey, user: firebase.User) => {
    logging.dev('Delete survey for: ' + survey.owner);

    const documentReference = firebase.firestore().collection('Surveys').doc(survey.id);

    if (survey.owner === user.uid) {
        documentReference
            .delete()
            .then(() => {
                logging.dev('Survey for ' + user.uid + ' has been deleted!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                logging.dev(error);
            });
    }
},

fetchSurvey: async (surveyId: string) => {
    logging.dev('Fetch single survey with ID: ' + surveyId);
    return await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('Surveys')
        .doc(surveyId)
        .get()
        .then((surveyDoc) => {
            return surveyDoc.data() as Survey;
        });
},

fetchSurveysByUser: (userId: string): Promise<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>> => {
    logging.dev('Fetch surveys by user id: ' + userId);
    return firebase.firestore().collection('Surveys').where('owner', '==', userId).get();
},
```

beside the sign in or logout functions provided by firebase. The only listener is "firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged".
Every query has its own logging, so I am pretty sure, every functions is just called once.
The only suspicious thing I've noticed, are the 4 channels which get opened everytime. I thought snapshot listener would only get opened, if I use onSnapshot, which I don't.

Now you know pretty much the whole application.
Am I doing something wrong which would explain such an amount of reads?

[image: reads]

EDIT: [image: channels]

Those channels are created after one single write. They all lok like that:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/
```

after a couple of seconds a forth - sometimes a fifth channel gets opened and that one looks like this:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects
```

I don't understand why there are 3 writes and I dont understand why that listener gets opened. But I am not sure if that relates to such an amount of reads.

Comment: "the 4 channels which get opened everytime" - What do you mean by channels (do you mean connections)?  Every time what happens?  What exactly are you doing to reproduce the unexpected behavior?  There should be enough information here that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that thats an interesting info, but I've added them. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: It is still unclear what exactly is the unexpected behavior, and it will be hard for anyone to replicate or reproduce your issue. Additionally, there's a guide for [best practices in read and write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#read_and_write_operations) for your reference.

Comment: What do you mean? There is text, code and images regarding the amount of reads and listeners, without calling any onSnapshot method or having queries called multiple times. Thats the unexpected behaviour. I know the site you are referencing to. But as I've already mentioned, a single write is everything you need to recreate it. I can add the additional info, that a single fetch, opens multiple listeners.

Comment: Your concern appears to require further investigation, and includes checking of your billing history and its usage. Have you tried to reach the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support)?